# SQL SUM on aggregate function

Tags: sql, t-sql

Perhaps I'm trying to be too clever for my own good, and I could possibly use a scalar variable to solve this.  I'm trying to add 1 to my output from the subquery;

```
INSERT INTO bookrevisiontbl (revisionnum, bookdate)
SELECT SUM(MAX(revisionnum) + 1), GETDATE() FROM bookrevisiontbl_tbl
```

However the following error occurs

> Cannot perform an aggregate function
>   on an expression containing an
>   aggregate or a subquery.

Is this query possible, and for it to maintain

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO bookrevisiontbl (revisionnum, bookdate)
SELECT MAX(revisionnum) + 1, GETDATE() FROM bookrevisiontbl_tbl
```

No need for sum as max will return single value

Comment: @wonea, did you think about setting some sort of an auto_increment integer to `revisionnum`?

Comment: Agreed, I'm a little embrassed. ;-)